# Refrescar un grafico en codigo python canvas

Tags: python, matplotlib, canvas, plot, widget

Quisiera saber si estoy haciendo algo mal. Tengo un script en el cual hace unos calculos y los datos me los tiene que graficar cuando selecciono en una tabla que tiene datos. En esta tabla selecciiono una fila y me tiene que graficar los datos de esa fila, pero si seleccionara otra me tendria que graficar los datos de la otra refrescando el grafico.
El problema que tengo es que me genera el primer grafico al seleccionar una fila pero luego se queda ahi y no me dibuja el proximo que seleccione. Y al cerrar la ui me aparece en el historial de plots del Spyder todos los graficos que no se mostraron.
Adjunto la parte del codigo que se encarga de graficar.

```
class VentanaPrincipal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VentanaPrincipal, self).__init__()
        loadUi('diseño.ui', self)
        self.tableWidget.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.mostrar_grafico)

    def crear_grafico(self, row):
        # Obtener los datos de la fila seleccionada
        fila = [self.tableWidget.item(row, col).text() for col in range(1, self.tableWidget.columnCount())]
    
        leyenda = f"{fila[0]} ({fila[1]})"
        datos_grafico = [float(valor) for valor in fila[2:]]  # Convertir los valores a flotantes
        print(datos_grafico)
    
        # Configurar los valores de X y Y
        x = [63, 125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000]
        y = np.arange(0, 101, 5)  # Valores de 50 a 100, cada 5 unidades
    
        # Configurar los ticks del eje X con los valores y el texto deseado
        xticks = x
        xticklabels = [str(valor) + " Hz" for valor in xticks]
    
        # Configurar los ticks del eje Y con los valores y el texto deseado
        yticks = y
        yticklabels = [str(valor) + " dB" for valor in yticks]
    
        # Configurar el gráfico
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.semilogx(x, datos_grafico, marker='o')
        ax.set_xlabel('Eje X')
        ax.set_ylabel('Eje Y')
        ax.set_title(leyenda)
        ax.grid(True)
    
        # Establecer los ticks personalizados en el eje X e Y
        ax.set_xticks(xticks)
        ax.set_xticklabels(xticklabels)
        ax.set_yticks(yticks)
        ax.set_yticklabels(yticklabels)
    
        # Crear el widget Canvas para mostrar el gráfico
        canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
        canvas.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    
        # Agregar el widget Canvas al layout del marco
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.widgetGrafico)
        layout.addWidget(canvas)
        self.widgetGrafico.setLayout(layout)
    
        # Dibujar el gráfico y procesar los eventos para mostrarlo
        fig.canvas.draw()
        fig.canvas.flush_events()



    
    def mostrar_grafico(self):
        # Obtener la fila seleccionada
        selected_row = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
        
        # Llamar a la función crear_grafico() con la fila seleccionada
        self.crear_grafico(selected_row)
```

Desde ya gracias por la ayuda.